# Forgetting a label and then output a new value for that label after every button push in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I tried to do `pack_forget()` however I have no idea to place it within the "final" function

```
userinput = Entry()
userinput.pack(side=TOP)
text = str(userinput)


def final():
    choices = ["It is certain", "It is decidedly so", "Without a doubt", "Yes definitely", "You may rely on it", "As I see it, yes", 
        "Most likely", "Outlook good", "Yes", 'Signs point to yes', "Reply hazy try again", "Ask again later", "Better not tell you now",
        "Cannot predict now", "Concentrate and ask again", "Dont count on it", "My reply is no", "My sources say no", "Outlook not good", 'Very doubful']

    if  len(text) > 0 :
        response = Label(root, text = random.choice(choices), bg = "snow")
        response.pack(side=TOP)




decision = Button(root, text = "Go", command = final)
decision.configure(font=(28))
decision.pack(side=TOP)
```

I believe that the `pack.forget()` needs to be inside the function (at least as far as I know), however, I have no idea how to forget the the response label after every button press and have it output a new response.

Comment: Your `while True` loop will never exit since `text` will never change inside of the loop.

Comment: @BryanOakley I removed the loop and the problem remains

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to use `.pack_forget()` you can use `.configure()` on the label instead, something like the below:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.choices = ["It is certain", "It is decidedly so", "Without a doubt", "Yes definitely", "You may rely on it", "As I see it, yes", "Most likely", "Outlook good", "Yes", 'Signs point to yes', "Reply hazy try again", "Ask again later", "Better not tell you now","Cannot predict now", "Concentrate and ask again", "Dont count on it", "My reply is no", "My sources say no", "Outlook not good", 'Very doubful']
        self.label = Label(self.root)
        self.button = Button(self.root, text="Ok", command=self.shuffle)
        self.label.pack()
        self.button.pack()
    def shuffle(self):
        self.label.configure(text=random.choice(self.choices))

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```